# DNS.query vs Socket.gethostbyname

Tags: python, sockets, networking, dns

What is different between python DNS.query and socket.gethostbyname, and which one is more accurate?

i am using DNS.query to find the IPv4 for a website. socket.gethostbyname do same task. so what is the different and which one is faster and more accurate for building a python browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "accurate" in your context.

A system has many ways to resolve a name. It can use content from `/etc/hosts`. It can use LDAP. It can use Windows name resolution. And it can use DNS. And many other things.

On Linux systems you have a file called `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that tells the system how you want to resolve names. You may have in it for example a line like:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

which means that on this host, to resolve a name, the system will first search in `/etc/hosts` and then if not found, go to the DNS.

So `socket.gethostbyname` will ask the OS for the name, hence will use the mechanism above.

If you use `DNS.query`, you "just" do a DNS query, nothing more. If the name to resolve is only in `/etc/hosts`, you will not be able to resolve it.

So what is accurate depends on your constraints and context. Both calls do different things.

Also as explained in documentation you should use `getaddrinfo` instead of `gethostbyname` anyway:

> gethostbyname() does not support IPv6 name resolution, and
>   getaddrinfo() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack support.

Comment: thanks patrick. the answer really helped to understand both methods and chose based on the case.